# Is it possible with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a below string. I need to find the dates before a particular string. is it possible with regex in C#. if so pls provide me an example.

String is

```
*044*05/02/2013*14:24*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 
OPERATION OK


*044*05/02/2013*14:24*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 


*044*05/02/2013*14:24*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 
OPERATION OK


[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162*054*05/04/2013*14:27*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 


*055*05/04/2013*14:27*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 
OPERATION OK


[020t*057*05/04/2013*14:27*
[05p
           BNA CNTRS
  LAST CLEARED : 00/00/00 00:00
                 COUNT 
  ENCASHED       141

[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162*065*05/05/2013*14:30*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*0, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 
OPERATION OK


*071*05/06/2013*14:31*
*1234*1*(Iw(1*1, M-00, R-10011002100310041
A/C 
CUSTOMER CANCEL


[020t*076*05/06/2013*14:32*
[05p
           BNA CNTRS
  LAST CLEARED : 05/04/13 14:28
                 COUNT 
  ENCASHED       11
```

In the above string i want to find the date before the string "BNA CNTRS". In this string, i should get that dates as "05/04/2013" "05/06/2013".

Comment: Is the `[05p` part always fixed? It looks to me like you could just look for `* [05p BNS CNTRS` and then take the 10 characters starting 15 characters before that index. No regex required.

Comment: Do you mean the _Last cleared_ date or the date in the header (between the asterisks)?

Comment: in some cases there will be a plenty of data between the date and the BNA CNTRS string. We dont know exactly where that date is located before the BNA CNTRS string.

Comment: Hi Jasd, consider date in the header. not in LAST CLEARED.

Comment: C#/.net is one of the few regex flavors that actually has the option to *search backwards*. You could find the position of "BNA CNTRS" then use a regex (`\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`) to search backwards from that point.

Comment: Thanks Mark. RegexOptions.RightToLeft is providing me the matches what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `\*(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})[^/]*?BNA CNTRS`

I'm using the explicit capture, singleline options here on the regex.

Regex hero link: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=c6694c7e-7777-4cc0-ab76-8846ef365330

Answer (score 0):

You can first substring till the said words "BNA CNTRS" and then get desired date string. But make sure above mention format will not gonna change as its having dependency on "BNA CNTRS".

Comment: in some cases there will be a plenty of data between the date and the BNA CNTRS string. We dont know exactly where that date is located before the BNA CNTRS string.

Comment: Correct me if I've interpreted wrong that you wanna get value of "LAST CLEARED" immediately after "BNA CNTRS", isn't it? If yes, you can have double check on it.

Comment: No, I need a date just before the BNA CNTRS. And there will be so much of data between the date and BNA CNTRS, not exactly like the same as given in example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://rubular.com/r/wPaKr3XCDS) match with the following regex:

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(?=[^(BNA)]+BNA CNTRS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your pattern Try this:

```
string strRegex = @"(?=(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}))(?=([^\n]+\n)+[^\n]*BNA\sCNTRS[^=\n]*\n)([^\n]+\n)+";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Singleline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"......"; #text you want to search

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    System.Out.println(myMatch.groups(1).value);
  }
}
```

Demo: [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/tT1mX2)